# expl3: lowercase sequence elements with line break breaks

Tags: macros, expl3, programming

I have some short text (book author names) stored in a sequence. Some author names are long, and therefore I have to insert manually a line break (`\\`). In a specific case, I have to typeset these names completely lowercase.

Thanks to the help of [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright), the [LowerCase works fine with text that contains the paragraph breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328550/2483) (`\\`).

But now, I store the text in a  sequence `\g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq` and then I create a new sequence with the lowercased text `\g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq` using `\seq_map_function:NN`.

When I try to print the names with `\seq_use:Nn` I get compilation errors.
If the names don't have  `\\` it works fine. But if there are some \; it only works when the string containing the `\\` token is in the last position of the sequence. 
(It doesn't matter if I use `\\`, `\par` or `\newline`). I get an error message like this

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> ... }{Author NameOne \\ TooLong}\\
                                                  \__xparse_start_expandable...
l.54     \printauthorslowercase
```

If instead of `\\` in the `\seq_use:Nn`, I use a `;` character the error looks like this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \\

l.54     \printauthorslowercase
```

Below is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \LowerCase { m }
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__texnik_newline: \\
    \cs_set_protected:Npx \\ { \exp_not:o \\ }
    \tl_lower_case:n {#1}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \\ \__texnik_newline:
  }

\cs_new:Npn \add_lowerauthor #1
{
  \tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl {\LowerCase{#1}}
  \seq_gput_right:No \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq {\l_tmpa_tl}
  \seq_log:N \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq
}


\seq_new:N \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mainauthor} {m} {%
  \seq_put_right:Nn \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq {#1}
}


\seq_new:N \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \printauthorslowercase { }
  {
    \seq_map_function:NN \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq \add_lowerauthor
    \seq_use:Nn \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq  {;}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

%% This works
% \mainauthor{Author NameOne}
% \mainauthor{Author NameTwo}

%%% This also works
% \mainauthor{Author NameOne}
% \mainauthor{Author NameTwo \\ TooLong}

%%% This doesn't works
\mainauthor{Author NameOne \\ TooLong}
\mainauthor{Author NameTwo}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[align=left] (text1)
  {%
    \printauthorslowercase
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Observation: the entry with ``\\`` only works if it is the last one, your data which you state works, has ``\\`` in the last entry, the other one does not. Why even the need for manual break, why not use `\raggedright`?

Comment: I rewrite a bit to make it clearer I hope :-). These macros are used to produce book covers, where I need total control of where the line breaks are inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow, but I don't see problems in passing `\\` to `\text_lowercase:n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mainauthor} {m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \printauthorslowercase { }
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq \sbmcpm_add_lowerauthor:n
  \seq_use:Nn \l_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq  {;}
 }

\seq_new:N \g_sbmcpm_listofauthors_seq
\seq_new:N \l_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sbmcpm_add_lowerauthor:n #1
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_sbmcpm_listofauthors_lowercase_seq { \text_lowercase:n {#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\mainauthor{Author NameOne \\ TooLong}
\mainauthor{Author NameTwo}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[align=left] (text1)
  {%
    \printauthorslowercase
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you follow the link of the previous question (at the top) and then another link to a previous question :-); Joseph said that "The only issue is that `\\` is not engine robust and the implementation of  `\tl_lower_case:n` expects 'text' to be either character tokens, things which expand to character tokens or engine-robust command". HIs answer dates back to Sep 1, 2016. At that time it didn't work. Has the implementation of `\tl_lower_case:n` change?

Comment: Dear egreg, I took some much time to accept your answer because, even your solution was working fine in the MWE, it was failing in real case.  I am using the `bookcover` class, but when I load the `pst-barcode` package, the document breaks. I managed to remove the dependency of `pst-barcode`; so now my problem is fixed.